# When is disk cache cleared on iOS?

Tags: ios

I'm using the cache to store a bunch of rendered thumbnails for my game. It can easily go up to 60MB if the user has all the content in the game.

I wonder if I need to clear this out myself? Does the OS do this for me, and if so when?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I had an issue with the documents directory on IOS5 I found [this](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/data-management/local-file-storage-in-ios-5) article which discusses the cache amongst other subjects.

As I understand it; yes the OS handles the cache and it will clear it when disk space is low. What **low** actually means in size I do not know.